# Custom Classes without defining an HTML Element?

Tags: html, ckeditor, drupal-8

I am using CK Editor with Drupal 8. It is fairly easy to add custom classes to a "Styles" drop down menu. My problem is that I want to give my team a lot of options for custom classes on elements, and the way CK Editor wants you to define them are per element. I would love it if there were a way to define a custom class without an HTML element.

Here are some classes that work just fine:

```
h2.ultra-condensed-caps|H2 Ultra Condensed Caps
h3.light|H3 Light
h3.bold-condensed-caps|H3 Bold Condensed Caps
p.size-small|Paragraph small
p.size-large|Paragraph large
```

What I wish I could do, is this:

```
*.size-small|Small Element
*.size-large|Large Element
```

Without something like the star selector, I have to define every element and every class permutation, which can easily start to bloat.

Has anyone tried to do something similar, and how?